# Difference between Array(n) and [...Array(n)]

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function, spread-syntax

Why there is a difference in map() output in the below code?

```
var y = [1,2,2,1];

var t = y.map(ind => [...Array(ind)].map((_,i) => ind+""+i));
// This makes [ [ '10' ], [ '20', '21' ], [ '20', '21' ], [ '10' ] ]

var t1 = y.map(ind => Array(ind).map((_,i) => ind+""+i));
//[ [ <1 empty item> ], [ <2 empty items> ], [ <2 empty items> ], [ <1 empty item> ] ]
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: `.map` does not loop over scattered indices

Comment: @Rajesh that's probably the answer OP is looking for. You should make this an answer, with links and everything

Comment: @Peping Thanks! I have seen a post on this. Was looking for it only

Comment: As an alternative, you can use `Array.from({length: n}, (_, i) => ...)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is basically the reason you should avoid using the Array constructor to create arrays.

When passed a single number `n` as an argument, the `Array` constructor will return an array with length `n`, but no elements, also known as a *sparse* array. (Anything else passed to the Array constructor, a string, an object, two numbers, etc, will create a normal array with the passed arguments as elements in order).

Trying to `.map()` over this array will not work, since there are no items in it, which is why you get the same sparse arrays. Your `.map()` is a no-op.

Using `[...` (Same with `Array.from()`, by the way) on it, will "realize" the array turning `[ <1 empty item> ]` into `[undefined]` and `[ <2 empty items> ]` into `[undefined, undefined]`, an array with actual elements, whose values are `undefined`. `.map()` *does* work on this, so you get the result you expect.

In short, avoid the `Array` constructor.

Comment: The array constructor is a remnant from Ye Olde days of medieval JavaScript. The reasoning behind sparse arrays is foggy.

Comment: @Veeshoo To mark a question as "resolved", click on the green tick below the answer's score (that will mark that answer as "accepted"). I noticed you haven't done this for previous questions you've made, it would be nice if you could return to those questions and accept the answers that helped solve your problem (It makes things more organized for the site, rewards the answerer, and gives you a little bonus reputation as well!). You're welcome, hope you enjoy the site! :)